# what if my charger output is 5V 750mA for pi 2?

Tags: power, pi-2

By the RASPBERRY PI 2 MODEL B specs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

The power rate of it is 800 mA, what are the possible effects if the charger output is lower or higher than 800 mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely to have issues with that power supply, 700ma was the minimum required by the original Pi. As you state 800ma is the minimum requirement for model 2 Pi's. Under current can manifest in many ways including SD card corruption, system instability, WiFi connection issues etc.

As for using a charger that supplies greater than 800ma you can use any charger up to 2000ma without problems.

One extra note: don't rely on the label on the charger, many problems have been traced to chargers not delivering the current they advertised.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about what some blog claims. This may be "typical" but this depends on what you connect, and whether you overclock.

Try it and see. If the red light stays on it is OK. A higher rated PSU is recommended.